# Создание витрины (планограммы) в заданном диапазоне, есть ошибки

Tags: excel, vba

Пытаюсь сделать конструктор планограмм в рамках моего проекта на работе (стажер в JTI).

Каждую пачку сигарет копирую макросом с одного листа на другую с помощью гиперссылок. Также добавил три кнопки:

1 - очистка объектов в диапазоне (a2:o20),

2 - создание новой планограммы,

3 - копирование планограммы в отдельный excel-файл.

При создании новой планограммы справа, в большинстве случаев, в конце первого же ряда вылетает цифра "1" не пойми откуда. И это не удаляется первой кнопкой. Также, если создаваемая планограмма меньше диапазона (например 10х10), то остальная часть сетки остается и не удаляется (просто появляются границы в диапазоне a2:o20 и всё).

Вот так всё выглядит: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceKsQ.png

Здесь все коды трех кнопок:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Me.CommandButton1.Caption = "Скопировать в Excel"
Me.CommandButton1.BackColor = vbGreen
Me.CommandButton1.ForeColor = vbBlack
Dim n, m As Integer
For n = 1 To 30
If Range(Cells(2, n), Cells(2, n)).Value = 1 Then
    For m = 3 To 30
        If Range(Cells(m, n), Cells(m, n)).Value = 1 Then
        Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(m - 1, n - 1)).Copy
        Dim NewBook As Workbook
            Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
                NewBook.Worksheets(1).Paste
                NewBook.Worksheets(1).Range("a1. cc100").ColumnWidth = 5.57
                NewBook.Worksheets(1).Range("a1. cc100").RowHeight = 55.5
            With NewBook
            .Title = "Planograma1"
            End With
            Exit For
        End If
    Next m
    Exit For
End If
Next n
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Me.CommandButton2.Caption = "Очистить"
Me.CommandButton2.BackColor = vbGreen
Me.CommandButton2.ForeColor = vbBlack

Dim sh As Shape
Dim cell As Variant
For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:O20")
        If sh.TopLeftCell.Address = cell.Address Then
            sh.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next


Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A2:O20")

With rng.Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Color = vbBlack
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Me.CommandButton3.Caption = "Создать новую планограмму"
Me.CommandButton3.BackColor = vbGreen
Me.CommandButton3.ForeColor = vbBlack

Dim Counter_1 As Integer
Dim Counter_2 As Integer

     Counter_1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Высота витрины")
  If Counter_1 > 2 Then
 Counter_2 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Ширина витрины")
        If Counter_2 > 1 Then
            Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Counter_1 + 1, Counter_2)).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Counter_1 + 1, Counter_2)).BorderAround (9)
            Cells(Counter_1 + 2, Counter_2 + 1).Value = 1
            Cells(2, Counter_2 + 1).Value = 1
        End If
    End If
 End Sub
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как удалить вот ту ненужную часть сетки и избавиться от "1" при создании?

Заранее огромнейшее спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: В каком случае и где нужно ставить единицы? Пока что в последней процедуре видно, что единицы записываются ниже и правее границ планограммы. Зачем удалять сетку? Можно ее не рисовать или удалять столбцы. Если опишете детально  задачу (не *я делаю так*, а *нужно такое*), можно оптимизировать код, там есть неточности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем в коде каждый раз перезаписывать параметры кнопок?

```
Me.CommandButton2.Caption = "Очистить"
Me.CommandButton2.BackColor = vbGreen
Me.CommandButton2.ForeColor = vbBlack
```

Сразу задать в параметрах (*Properties*)

*Dim n, m As Long* - тип нужно задавать для каждой переменной. Сейчас *n* имеет тип *Variant*

Объявление переменных. *Dim* у Вас в цикле, строка срабатывает с каждым шагом цикла. Т.к. все переменные, объявленные в процедуре, занимают память при начале работы процедуры, можно все *Dim* разместить в начале процедуры.

*With* - оператор присвоения объекта переменной (плюс упрощения кода). Имеет смысл, если обращений к объекту много. Если один раз, так записывать излишне:

```
With NewBook                    
       .Title = "Planograma1"
End With
```

Если уж диапазон загоняете в память, то и использовать его нужно по максимуму

```
Set rng = Range("A2:O20")
```

строку разместить перед поиском и удалением объектов.

В диапазонах задавать можно столбцы/строки:

```
Columns("A:CC").ColumnWidth = 5.57
Rows("1:100").RowHeight = 55.5
```

Непонятно в строке:

```
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(m - 1, n - 1)).Copy
```

Цикл по *n* начинается с единицы. На первом шаге *n-1 = 0*. Но ячейки с нулевым столбцом не бывает!

```
Cells(m - 1, 0)
```

Еще одино замечание.

```
Range(Cells(m, n), Cells(m, n))
```

Читаем: диапазон от ячейки Cells(m, n) до ячейки Cells(m, n). Это же одна ячейка и можно записать эту строку так:

```
Cells(m, n)
```

Запись единиц при формировании нового диапазона убрал вообще.

В остальном смотрите правки.

' ==========================

```
' в новый файл'
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long, lClmn As Long
    i = Range("A1").Value ' последняя строка'
    lClmn = Range("B1").Value ' последний столбец'
    If i < 2 Or lClmn = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Set rng = Cells(2, 1).Resize(i - 1, lClmn)
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False: End With

    With Workbooks.Add
        With .Worksheets(1)
            .Columns("A").Resize(, lClmn).ColumnWidth = 5.57
            .Rows("2:" & i - 1).RowHeight = 55.5
            rng.Copy .Cells(2, 1).Resize(i - 1, lClmn)
            .name = "Planograma1"
        End With

        For i = .Sheets.Count To 2 Step -1
            .Sheets(i).Delete
        Next i
    End With

    Set rng = Nothing
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True: End With
End Sub

' удаление объектов'
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim sh As Shape
Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A2:O20")

    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Not Intersect(sh.TopLeftCell, rng) Is Nothing Then
            sh.Delete
        End If
    Next

    Set rng = Nothing
End Sub

' новя планограмма'
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim Counter_1 As Long, Counter_2 As Long
    With Range("A2:O20")
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone ' удаление границ'
        .ClearContents ' удаление значений'
    End With

    Range("A1:B1").Value = 0

    Counter_1 = Val(Application.InputBox(prompt:="Высота витрины"))
    If Counter_1 < 3 Then Exit Sub
    Counter_2 = Val(Application.InputBox(prompt:="Ширина витрины"))
    If Counter_2 < 2 Then Exit Sub

    If Counter_1 > 19 Then Counter_1 = 19
    If Counter_2 > 15 Then Counter_2 = 15
    ' чтобы не искать при создании книги, запоминаем границы диапазона'
    Range("A1").Value = Counter_1 + 1 
    Range("B1").Value = Counter_2

    With Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Counter_1 + 1, Counter_2))
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .BorderAround (9)
        .Borders.Color = vbBlack
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: огромное спасибо Вам за помощь! Всё работает, немного изменил кнопку очистки, вставил туда часть из новой планограммы (где .ClearContents и .Borders.Linestyle = x1None). Но появилась одна проблема: планограмма не хочет копироваться в отдельный файл, почему-то не срабатывает кнопка. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Так написал же - мне непонятна логика копирования данных. Плюс к этому - у Вас явная ошибка с нулевым столбцом. Опишите словами, где должны быть значения и как они там появляются (у ВАс в двух циклах проверка ячеек на равенство единице), что попадает в новый файл.

Comment: По идее он прогоняет каждую ячейку в заданном диапазоне, копирует всё в новую рабочую книгу, если есть контент - копирует вместе с ним, сохраняя все исходные параметры. С нулевым столбцом не знаю, что можно сделать, с vba я встретился 5 дней назад. То, что сейчас вышло - это чисто гугл и мои вялые попытки разобраться, как всё происходит

Comment: Можно ли копировать весь диапазон, ограниченный сеткой, без проверки каждой ячейки? Или не все из диапазона должно попасть в новую книгу? Зачем там вообще единицы??

Comment: Той сеткой, что задается при создании новой планограммы - да, конечно. Только с учетом того, чтобы копировал и контент в ячейках. Единицы не знаю зачем, тот код я просто слепил из всего, что находил в интернете. До этого получалось хоть что-то, а сейчас совсем застрял

Comment: Заменил в ответе процедуру создания книги

Comment: Большое спасибо. всё работает. Только один нюанс: он пропускает первую строку, планограмма 10х10 размещается со 2 по 11 строки, а параметры 11 строки не изменяются (пачка там не помещается)

Comment: Какой диапазон нужно копировать: с 1 по 11 строки или с 1 по 10-ю? Поппробуйте сами разобраться в записи диапазона. Изменить просто.

Comment: Да, разобрался, огромное спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Во первых:
Очистка диапазона можно достичь так- Range("A1:A6").Clear

А по поводу единицы 
Тебе эта строка зачем?

Cells(2, Counter_2 + 1).Value = 1

В ней ты говоришь, а поставь мне 1 за таблицей, например ширина таблицы указал 10, то в 11 ячейке он нарисует тебе 1 как на картинке.

Ещё совет. Есть функция макро рекордер, записал что захотел сделать, потом скопировал))

Comment: *Clear* удалит все (значения, сетку, заливку...), но объекты оставит )

Comment: Тогда так) Range("A1:A6").ClearContents